# Need to display distinct value

Tags: sql

Note:Table is not inserting correctly. Kindly understand

```
(Col1-ID,Col2-Name,Col3-Type(a1,b1,c1,d1),Col4-Year)
```

Table: Example1

This is my query,

```
select distinct name,type from example1 

Id   Name       Type   Year

1    sai         a1    2017

2    sai         b1    2016

3    sai         c1    2015

4    joe         a1    2016

5    Michael     c1    2015

6    Michael     d1    2013

7    Michael     a1    2012
```

and my query is, when I am selecting name and type from example1 table the result is shown below

```
Id   Name       Type   
1    sai         a1    
2    sai         b1        
3    joe         a1    
4    Michael     c1    
5    Michael     d1
```

I need a **latest year value** but **it displaying duplicate value(with latest year value and previous year value)**
Please help on this.

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: hint: aggregate query (group by and max). Take a SQL tutorial. As mentioned, this isn't a free code factory. If you've shown some effort (seems like you haven't) then the volunteers here will show some effort to help you. If there's no evidence that you've tried to research or code it yourself, then they generally won't.

Comment: the problem with your statement is that DINSTICT only removes distinct combinations, not distinct single values

Answer (score 0):

You can take the year for Year part of current date and use query with a WHERE clause for current year.

```
DECLARE @currYear INT = DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE())

select distinct name,type from example1 WHERE Year = @currYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning what you asked for, you selected the distinct name and type so that's what you will get, the distinct values for both those columns.

If you just want the distinct name then you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       name
FROM example1;
```

If you want the type too then you need to decide what aggregation you are going to do on it e.g. the max, min, count etc... Then you can use `GROUP BY`.

If you want the distinct name and the most recnet type then you can use:

```
SELECT
      name,
      MAX(type)
FROM example1
GROUP BY name
```

Also type and name are keywords in SQL, best practise is to not use those for column names

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY Statement

```
 Select name,type from example1 where year=YEAR(CURDATE()) group by name,type;
```

Comment: this won't compile I don't think. You need to group by type as well, or wrap it in an aggregate function (e.g. count, sum) as you feel is appropriate to the question